# Why are Java lambdas treated differently from nested classes with respect to instance field initialization?

Tags: javac

With javac 1.8.0_77 this class does not compile:

```java
    import java.util.function.*;
    public class xx {
        final Object obj;
    
        final Supplier<Object> supplier1 = new Supplier<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object get() {
                return xx.this.obj;
            }
        };
    
        final Supplier<Object> supplier2 = () -> { return this.obj; };
    
        xx(Object obj) {
            this.obj = obj;
        }
    }
```

Here's the error:

```
    xx.java:12: error: variable obj might not have been initialized
        final Supplier<Object> supplier2 = () -> { return this.obj; };
                                                              ^
    1 error
```

Questions:

1. Is the generation of this error correct according to the JLS?
2. If so, what is the reasoning behind the JLS treating a `@FunctionalInterface` lamba implementation (`supplier2`) differently from its equivalent inner class implementation (`supplier1`) in this respect?

**EDITED TO ADD (2022/9/21)**

FYI here's a simple compiler patch that fixes this. It causes lambdas to be treated like non-constructor methods with respect to field initialization (namely, ignore them) in `Flow.AssignAnalyzer`:

```
diff --git a/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Flow.java b/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Flow.java
index 20abb281211..7e77d594143 100644
--- a/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Flow.java
+++ b/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Flow.java
@@ -2820,30 +2909,33 @@ public class Flow {
         @Override
         public void visitLambda(JCLambda tree) {
             final Bits prevUninits = new Bits(uninits);
             final Bits prevInits = new Bits(inits);
             int returnadrPrev = returnadr;
+            int firstadrPrev = firstadr;
             int nextadrPrev = nextadr;
             ListBuffer<PendingExit> prevPending = pendingExits;
             try {
                 returnadr = nextadr;
+                firstadr = nextadr;
                 pendingExits = new ListBuffer<>();
                 for (List<JCVariableDecl> l = tree.params; l.nonEmpty(); l = l.tail) {
                     JCVariableDecl def = l.head;
                     scan(def);
                     inits.incl(def.sym.adr);
                     uninits.excl(def.sym.adr);
                 }
                 if (tree.getBodyKind() == JCLambda.BodyKind.EXPRESSION) {
                     scanExpr(tree.body);
                 } else {
                     scan(tree.body);
                 }
             }
             finally {
                 returnadr = returnadrPrev;
                 uninits.assign(prevUninits);
                 inits.assign(prevInits);
                 pendingExits = prevPending;
+                firstadr = firstadrPrev;
                 nextadr = nextadrPrev;
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsing through the JLS changes from JSR 335, this looks like an omission to me:

- Access to blank final fields is regulated by [JLS Chapter 16](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html)
- There is a section ["Definite Assignment and Anonymous Classes"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.6) which mandates the error in the case of `supplier1`.
- The [JSR 335 spec](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr335/index.html) has only one marginal change for chapter 16, never mentioning "lambda" or "method references" throughout this chapter.

In fact the only change in Chap.16 is (*using bold type face for additions*):

> Throughout the rest of this chapter, we will, unless explicitly stated otherwise, write V to represent an **in-scope (6.3)** local variable or a blank final field <s>(for rules of definite assignment) or a blank final variable (for rules of definite unassignment)</s>.

At the bottom line, compilers seem to be right in not complaining in the lambda case, but for consistency JLS should probably be amended to cover this case, too.

**Edit:**: OpenJDK already has a [spec bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8043176) for this, changes are being proposed as we speak.

Comment: Thanks for the bug reference.

Comment: The spec bug has been resolved, javac 9-ea+142 still rejects the program.

Comment: Is your question answered? _(Hint: accepting the answer would be nice :) )_.

Comment: Oops, forgot. Thanks!